# What happens if PID loop is too fast?

Tags: pid-controller

I have a PID loop running at 100Hz and is working reasonably well, for now. However, if I double the speed to 200Hz it no longer works, which isn't much of a surprise. The question is, what changes should be made to the PID values to get it to work at 200Hz? Is it a linear change in values? Can it be calculated? What is the relationship between stability and loop speed?

Comment: You need to adjust your `I` and `D` coefficients. Obviously `I` will now integrate *faster*, therefore the integral term will accumulate faster. On the other hand, the `D` term will now be smaller, because you differentiate over a shorter delta-t (unless you are already taking it in account). But this is a theory. The best thing is to re-tune it from scratch, because these might be not the only factors.

Comment: It could be linear or otherwise mappable/fittable or it could require calibration data for every operating point, can't tell without knowledge of the system being driven, it's not a PID generic thing.

Comment: Please mention the calculations / expressions you use to find the integral and derivative. If the derivative part directly comes from a dedicated rate sensor (say, a tacho generator), then D gain can also be kept same. It would be good if you could add more details of the setup.

Comment: How does the loop time compare to the process time constant? If you sample far too fast, the measurement noise might become bigger than real process changes.

Comment: Not sure what the process time constant is for a wobbling balance. I have measured it under some circumstances as being 16Hz

Answer (score 7):

When you execute a PID with higher sampling rate you can encounter two things:

- The integrator may not work properly if the new delta is very tiny. This is due to the final resolution of floating point number. Using a double precision float numbers significantly improves this problem until certain point (sampling frequency).
- The differentiator increases its output due to the input noise (also quantization noise). The output follows \$\dfrac{d\varepsilon}{dt}\$ so shorter sample time (higher freq.) means higher output for the same step change (quantization). A way to solve this phenomena is to use 1st order low pass filter on the D-part. However large filter times would also make the D-part unresponsive at high dynamics - right the opposite for what the D-Part is used for. Another countermeasure is to use a dead band on D-part input - a small change in the input signal is therefore neglected ( a good way to eliminate quantization noise)

Let we define a PID function as:
$$y=K_p \cdot(\varepsilon+\dfrac{1}{T_i}\int\varepsilon dt+ T_d \dfrac{d\varepsilon}{dt})$$

Then discrete form:
$$y=K_p\cdot(\varepsilon + \dfrac{\Delta T}{T_i}\Sigma\varepsilon + T_d\dfrac{\Delta\varepsilon}{\Delta T} )$$

Often is written also in this form:
$$y=k_p\varepsilon + k_i\Sigma\varepsilon + k_d\Delta\varepsilon$$

If your PID routine uses last form, you should re-calcuate ki,kd at every change of kp or sample time.

Comment: More important than the resolution of the floats is that the integrator will accumulate twice as fast. Thus the I-gain needs to be devided by two

Comment: @SimSon If \$k_i=K_p\cdot\dfrac{ T_{sample} }{T_i}\$ then with a new sampling time, which is half of the older, the ki also has to be only the half of the older. I hope that this is understandable from the equations I wrote.